# python replace adjacent part of a column in one csv with adjacent column data from another csv

Tags: python, csv

I have filea.csv and fileb.csv and I want to make filec.csv. filea has three columns of data:

```
date,PVkW,TBLkW
2014/12/26 16:00,20.0,307.4633
2014/12/26 17:00,0.0,291.6297
2014/12/26 18:00,0.0,240.87265
2014/12/26 19:00,0.0,251.475
2014/12/26 20:00,0.0,291.81406
2014/12/26 21:00,0.0,268.26328
2014/12/26 22:00,0.0,257.0367
```

fileb has two columns of data, with matching values for row[0] of filea, but fewer rows:

```
date,PVkW,TBLkW
2014/12/26 16:00,108.95
2014/12/26 17:00,1.84
2014/12/26 18:00,0.0
```

For filec, I am trying to replace row[1] in filea with that of fileb when they have the same row[0], and otherwise just write filea's row in filec:

```
date,PVkW,TBLkW
2014/12/26 16:00,108.95,307.4633
2014/12/26 17:00,1.84,291.6297
2014/12/26 18:00,0.0,240.87265
2014/12/26 19:00,0.0,251.475
2014/12/26 20:00,0.0,291.81406
2014/12/26 21:00,0.0,268.26328
2014/12/26 22:00,0.0,257.0367
```

Here's what I am working with, adapted from [python update a column value of a csv file according to another csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407427/python-update-a-column-value-of-a-csv-file-according-to-another-csv-file)

```
import csv

filea = "filea.csv"
fileb = "fileb.csv"
filec = "filec.csv"

delim = ","

a_content = csv.reader(open(filea,"r"), delimiter=delim)
b_content = csv.reader(open(fileb,"r"), delimiter=delim)
datawriter = csv.writer(open(filec, "w"), delimiter=delim)

b_dict = {}

next(b_content)

for row in b_content:
    b_dict[row[0]] = row[1] 

for row in a_content:
    if row[0] in b_dict:
       row[1] = b_dict[row[1]]

    datawriter.writerow(row)
```

When I run it (python3), I get the following error:

```
row[1] = b_dict[row[1]]
KeyError: '0'
```

How might I produce filec from filea and fileb as described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the way you are referencing the key in `b_dict` in the line `row[1] = b_dict[row[1]]` is wrong, it should be `row[1] = b_dict[row[0]]`, since `row[0]` is the key of the dictionary, not `row[1]`.

Comment: You are right. I made a silly mistake, but hopefully this will serve as an example for others. Thanks.